# Gold Bar in Winforms

Tags: winforms, user-controls, user-interface, notifications

I need to create a Gold bar for my windows form similar to what is shown when asked to install Active X controll. Is there one available?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/InformationBar.aspx) and i like it